# What is a "yield return" equivalent in the D programming language?

Tags: d, dmd

Here is a simple generator in C#.

```
    IEnumerable<int> Foo()
    {
        int a = 1, b = 1;
        while(true)
        {
            yield return b;
            int temp = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }
    }
```

How do I write a similar generator in *Digital Mars* D?

(The question is about the *yield return* statement)

Thanks!

---

Update.
That's interesting. Since I'm just generating a mathematical sequence, using [**recurrence**](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_range.html) may be a good option.

```
auto fib = recurrence!("a[n-1] + a[n-2]")(1, 1);

foreach (e; take(fib, 10)) // <- prints first ten numbers from the sequence
{ 
    writeln(e); 
}
```

Comment: Note that you should be able to write fib.take(10) by now cause Uniform Function Call Syntax has been enhanced.

Comment: Even found the article: http://www.drdobbs.com/blogs/cpp/232700394

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's no *exact* equivalent in D.  Here are some rough equivalents:

Using opApply-style internal iteration.  This doesn't allow iterating over two iterators in lockstep, though:

```
struct Foo {
    int opApply(int delegate(ref int) dg) {
        int a = 1, b = 1;
        int result;
        while(true) {
            result = dg(b);
            if(result) break;
            int temp = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

void main() {
    // Show usage:
    Foo foo;
    foreach(elem; foo) {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}
```

Use ranges.  These are slightly harder to write in some cases, but are very efficient and allow lockstep iteration.  This can also be iterated over with a `foreach` loop, exactly like the `opApply` version:

```
struct Foo {
    int a = 1, b = 1;

    int front() @property {
        return b;
    }

    void popFront() {
        int temp = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

    // This range is infinite, i.e. never empty.
    enum bool empty = false;

    typeof(this) save() @property { return this; }
}
```

If you **really** need coroutine-style stuff you can combine ranges and opApply together using `core.thread.Fiber`, but you'll probably find that either ranges or opApply does what you need almost all the time.

Comment: While the D version is a little more verbose, it is at least more readable: I just can't get myself over that Foo should return 1 every time (b is assigned 1 in the very beginning). Also every language does things a little differently, for example Ruby is basically the opApply version without the struct overhead.

Comment: @he_the_great:  The other tradeoff is that both D versions are much more efficient.  While coroutine/generator style iteration can be simulated using fibers, I think pretty syntax for it was intentionally omitted because it costs about a hundred cycle context switch on each iteration.  The opApply version costs maybe 5 or 10 cycles for the delegate call, and the range version can cost nothing compared to a hand-coded version because all of the range primitives are eligible for inlining.  One of these two styles will do what you need w/o much trouble about 99.9% of the time.

Comment: Thanks, dsimcha. Using ranges looks very promising, I shall look it up.

Answer (score 20):

See [here](https://github.com/pszturmaj/dgenerators); example excerpt below:

```
module main;

import std.stdio;
import generators;

void genSquares(out int result, int from, int to)
{
    foreach (x; from .. to + 1)
        yield!result(x * x);
}

void main(string[] argv)
{
    foreach (sqr; generator(&genSquares, 10, 20))
        writeln(sqr);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

The `std.concurrency` module now has a `Generator` class which makes this even easier (and you don't need a third-party library).

The class is an input range, so it can be used with for loops and all the standard `std.range`/`std.algorithm` functions.

```c++
import std.stdio;
import std.range;
import std.algorithm;
import std.concurrency : Generator, yield;

void main(string[] args) {
    auto gen = new Generator!int({
        foreach(i; 1..10)
            yield(i);
    });

    gen
        .map!(x => x*2)
        .each!writeln
    ;
}
```

Comment: I am quite sure the `Generator` template did not exist when question was asked...